# Showing a sub-table under Material-table detail panel

Tags: json, reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I am trying to add [dense table](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/#dense-table) under [material-table detail panel](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/detail-panel) but couldn't managed to do it.

I want to show **id**, **project_name** and **links** on the main table and when you click the project rows it should show that projects **features** array as a sub-table.

Here what I tried to do but it currently it shows every feature on every row.
Thanks in advance.

https://repl.it/@CagatayCanK/Create-React-App

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `detailPanel`, instead of looper over all of your data, you need to loop only over the `features` that are part of the current row:

```
  detailPanel={(rowData) => {
    return (
      <div id="project-features">
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
          <Table size="small">
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>Features</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {rowData.features.map((feature) => (
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell component="th" scope="row">
                    {feature}
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      </div>
    );
  }}
```